# Binding DTO in WPF - I want to only display the Filename. Currently it's displaying the "DTO"

Tags: c#

I got my Listbox binding to my BindableCollection but I want to only display the Filename. Currently it's displaying the "DTO"

```
public class FilesDTO : IDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileArray { get; set; }
}

using (var ctx = DB.Get())
    {
         Files = new BindableCollection<FilesDTO>(ctx.Files.Select(x => new FilesDTO { FileArray = x.  FileArray, FileExtension = x.FileExtension, FileName = x.FileName, Id = x.Id }));
    }
```

Xaml side:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Attachments" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"  />
```

I tried {Binding Files.Filename} doesn't work either. My guess is creating properties to bind to :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemsTemplate` to display your member appropriately.  For example, the following will display the list of files using a simple `TextBlock`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Attachments" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the DisplayMemberPath:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="FileName" />
```